# How to receive values of html div tag with specific class?

Tags: php, html, regex

I am parsing an HTML string, but I have a problem. I would like to get the values inside of the `div`s with the class of `product__info__value` using regex but not with the client side DOM.

I have tried the following code:

`$reg_ex = "<div[^<>]*class=\"my-class\"[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?</div>";`

But it didn't really work for me.

This is the html input:

```
<div class="product__info__group">
    <div class="product__info__name">Производитель</div>
    <div class="product__info__value">Holzhof</div>
</div>
<div class="product__info__group">
    <div class="product__info__name">Страна</div>
    <div class="product__info__value"></div>
</div>
```

I need these values in array form:
`Производитель, Holzhof, Страна`

Thank you very much for help, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break it into 3 parts.  The part before the name/value, the actual name/value that you want and something after the name/value.

1. `product__info__(?:name|value)">` # THE END OF THE TAG
2. `(?:[^<]+)`  # ANYTHING THAT'S NOT AN OPENING ANGLE BRACKET
3. `(?=<)`  # A LOOKAHEAD WITH AN OPENING ANGLE BRACKET

All put together, it would look like this:

```
preg_match_all('~product__info__(?:name|value)">\K(?:[^<]+)(?=<)~', $string, $matches);
```

[Here is a demo](https://ideone.com/nTBTbu)